# bribing in second price auctions

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, game-theory, auction-theory

In this [paper](http://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/schummer/ftp/research/bbribe/bbribe2.pdf), they analyse a second-price auction game with an option for the first player to bribe the second player to stay out of he game.

In proposition 2, they show that for any $b\in(0, \Bbb{E}[\theta_i])$ there exists a sequential equilibrium in which bribing occurs, and there exist $A^b$ and $B^b$ such that the sets of bribers and acceptors are $[B^b, 1]$ and $[0, A^b]$

I am interested in finding those $A^b$ and $B^b$, more specifically I am interested in how Figure 1 was generated (the equilibrium values of A and B as a function of b under the uniform distribution). I wish to calculate the area between A and B, and the difference between them also as function of b.
I also wish to better understand how did they achieve this results as I am trying to develop similar results for a more general case (with 3 players)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure $1$ has two parts – one where $A$ and $B$ are both in equilibrium, and one where $A$ takes on its maximal value $1$ and only $B$ is in equilibrium.

For $B$ to be in equilibrium, the bribing player must be indifferent at $B$ whether to bribe or not. If she bribes, the integral of her payoff over the accepting types of the bribed player is just $A(B-b)$, whereas if she doesn't, it's

$$
\int_0^B\mathrm d\theta_i(B-\theta_i)=\frac12B^2\;,
$$

so the equilibrium condition for $B$ is

$$
A(B-b)=\frac12B^2\;.
$$

(The integral over the rejecting types of the bribed player isn't affected by whether she bribes.)

For $A$ to be in equilibrium, the bribed player must be indifferent at $A$ whether to accept the bribe or not. If he accepts, the integral of his payoff over the bribing types of the bribing player is just $(1-B)b$, whereas if he rejects, it's

$$
\int_B^A\mathrm d\theta_j(A-\theta_j)=\frac12(A-B)^2\;,
$$

so the equilibrium condition for $A$ is

$$
(1-B)b=\frac12(A-B)^2\;.
$$

(Again, the integral over the non-bribing types isn't affected by whether he'd hypothetically accept.)

Now we can use these to treat the two cases in Figure $1$. In the right-hand part, $A=1$ is fixed, and only the equilibrium condition for $B$ applies; substituting $A=1$ into it and solving the resulting quadratic equation for $B$ yields

$$
B=1\pm\sqrt{1-2b}\;.
$$

In the left-hand part, both $A$ and $B$ are in equilibrium, so we can use both equilibrium conditions to find $A$ and $B$. Solving the equilibrium condition for $B$ for $A$,

$$
A=\frac{B^2}{2(B-b)}\;,
$$

and substituting into the equilibrium condition for $A$ yields a quartic equation for $B$:

$$
(B-b)^2(1-B)b=\frac18B^2(B-2b)^2\;.
$$

[Here's a plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20(x-b)%5E2%20(1-x)%20b%20%3D%201%2F8%20*%20x%5E2%20(x-2b)%5E2%20for%20x%3D0..1). I'll leave it to you to figure out which of the branches is a stable equilibrium in each case. In view of the quartic equation for $B$ (or cubic for $b$), calculating the area between $A$ and $B$ will probably best be done numerically.

Comment: Thx, but  Im not sure I understand this plot, it looks like for every $0\le b \le 1$ there are 2 solutions, how can I know which is the solution Im looking for? comparing to the plot in the paper it looks like he took the middle part (that starts with the edgy end, and goes up to almost 1 at the point where B is 0.5), but why? also in the plot at the paper is seems like its starting from b=B=0 and ends at b=0.5, B=1, where is the same line in your plot only starts a bit after 0 and ends a bit before

Comment: @DanielKatzan: I think the fact that it doesn't start at $b=B=0$ is just an artifact of Wolfram|Alpha's plotting code that's being thrown off by the sharp cusp in the curve at that point. As for the other end, recall that this solution only applies when $A$ is in equilibrium. In the plot in the paper, it appears that this is the case up to about $b=0.3$ or so. After that, the solution with $A$ fixed at the maximal value $1$ takes over. As for which of the branches to use: I only used the first-order equilibrium conditions. For an equilibrium, the second derivatives have to have the right sign.

Comment: Im still struggling in finding the equation to plot for $A$ as a function of $b$ when $A \lt 1$

Comment: BTW, looking at the [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%3D1-sqrt(1-2b)+for+b%3D0..1) for $B$ where $A= 1$, it seems a bit like the plot in the paper is just that plot, do u think that is possible?

Comment: @DanielKatzan: It's hard to tell with the naked eye, but if you look closely you might be able to discern the slight kink in the graph at the transition point. I made it more visible here by superimposing a plot of the solution for $A=1$ onto the entire graph: https://ibb.co/mV2BZy. The $A=1$ solution is the thin line in purple; I aligned it so that it's on the right-hand edge of the thick black plot from the paper both at the origin and at $(0.5,1)$; you can see that it precisely tracks the right-hand edge of the paper's plot where $A=1$ and deviates slightly where $A\lt1$.

Comment: @DanielKatzan: To plot $A(b)$ for $A\lt1$, you can solve one of the two equilbrium conditions (which are both quadratic in $B$) for $B$ and substitute into the other one to get $A$ in terms of $b$. It's going to be a slightly ugly equation, but you can either let Wolfram|Alpha plot it or turn it into a nicer algebraic equation by isolating the square root(s) and squaring (you may have to do that more than once).

Comment: maybe you can help with another related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2858606/calculating-inefficiency-in-second-price-auction-with-bribe)? @joriki