# Calculating inefficiency in second price auction with bribe

Tags: calculus, integration, algorithmic-game-theory

Following a previous related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2824112/bribing-in-second-price-auctions/2824773?noredirect=1#comment5849301_2824773) of mine, regarding this [paper](https://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/schummer/ftp/research/bbribe/bbribe2.pdf) on bribing in a second price auctions.

I am interested in calculating the chance for inefficiency to occur (i.e. the chance that the bribing player will win the auction although he doesn't have the highest valuation)

Inefficiency will occur if the bribing player will offer the bribe ($\theta_j > B^b)$ and the bribed player will accept the bribe  $(\theta_i > A^b)$ and  $ \theta_i > \theta_j$.

In the case of uniform distribution this happens with probability of $\frac{(A^b - B^b)^2}{2}$

Assuming $b$ is also uniformly distributed, I want to calculate

$$\int_0^\frac{1}{2} \frac{(A^b - B^b)^2}{2} db$$

I split this integral into 2 cases, where $A=1$, and where $A<1$ 
The case where $A=1$ is rather simple and I was able to calculate it

But when $A<1$  we have $$(B-b)^2(1-B)b=\frac18B^2(B-2b)^2$$ 
$$A=\frac{B^2}{2(B-b)}$$
 I am not able to isolate the formula for $B$ and therefore cant manage to calculate this integral.

Comment: There seems to be some amount of confusion (not just in your question) about whether there should be a square in the probability. You first state it with the square, but then in the integral you don't have the square. On page $9$ in the paper, they state the probability without the square, but the argument they provide for it seems to lead to the square, so that looks like a typo to me. But in the previous question you also spoke about calculating the area between $A$ and $B$, without a square. I would have thought there should be a square; perhaps you can confirm that or explain why not?

Comment: I believe it was a typo in the paper, and it was also a typo in my question, I have edited it

Comment: Note that the integrand is the right-hand side of the equilibrium condition for $A$ (from my answer to the other question):

$$
(1-B)b=\frac12(A-B)^2\;.
$$

So it would be enough to be able to integrate $Bb$ -- but even that looks difficult to do analytically.